# Firebase data not saving

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase and am trying to save the user object (users email) to the database through the `.then()` on the `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`

When I try to do this it throws an error:

> FIREBASE WARNING: set at /users/-KlMikr6xZnfYC6dFJ6L failed: permission_denied

Basically saying I don't have permission to set the user data to the user node.

I know the function works when, because when I set the security write rules to true the `userobj` is created in the database.

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

controller.js

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('appCtrl', function($scope){

    //empty user object to store info
    $scope.user = {};

    //empty object to accept user password
    $scope.password = {};

    // add login event
    $scope.signUp = function(){
      const email = $scope.user.email;
      const password = $scope.password.setup;

      // create new firebase user
      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        // add user object to database
        .then(function(){
          var userObj = $scope.user;
          console.log($scope.user);

          // set up database references
          let database = firebase.database();
          let ref = database.ref();
          let usersRef = ref.child('users');

          // push user object to database
          usersRef.push(userObj);

        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          // Handle Errors here.
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
          console.log(errorCode);
          console.log(errorMessage);
        });   
    };

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in.
        console.log('user signed in');
        var uid = user.uid;
        console.log(uid);
      } else {
        // No user is signed in.
        console.log('user not signed in');
      }
    });

  })
```

Firebase database rules

```
"rules": {
  "users": {
    "$uid": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "(auth.uid === $uid)"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: obviously you can't have the uid match before the user is created, so thats the error. but simply opening the rule for that data might not be secure. I'd like to see the answer to this. voting up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you are using **.push()**, that creates child with new UID.
You should retrieve newly created user UID, and assign your object to related reference.

```
let uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
let usersRef = ref.child('users').child(uid);
usersRef.set(userObj);
```